# Impossible to get nuget package from another gitlab project (error NU1301)

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, nuget-package, container-registry

I installed Gitlab locally. I have two projects: a toolkit (project 1) and a second project (project 2) which uses the nuget package from this first project. The nuget package is stored in Gitlab's package registry of project 1.

I want to create a docker image of project 2 and store it in the Gitlab container registry of project 2.

My gitlab-ci.yml file is as follows:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy-solution:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --build-arg TOKEN=$CI_JOB_TOKEN --no-cache .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  only:
    - main
```

My nuget.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="gitlab" value="https://<localdomain>/api/v4/projects/<project1_id>/packages/nuget/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <gitlab>
      <add key="Username" value="gitlab-ci-token" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="$TOKEN_ENV" />
    </gitlab>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

## Certificates SSL
WORKDIR /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY ["ca.crt", "."]
RUN update-ca-certificates -f

## Copy sources and build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["nuget.config", "."]
ARG TOKEN
ENV TOKEN_ENV=$TOKEN
#RUN sed -i "s/PASSWORD/$TOKEN_ENV/" nuget.config <-- By replacing a keyword in the nuget.config file
COPY ["Project2.API/Project2.API.csproj", "Project2.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Project2.API/Project2.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project2.API"
RUN dotnet build "Project2.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

# Publish
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project2.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Deploy
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project2.API.dll"]
```

The command in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file `docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE --build-arg TOKEN=$CI_JOB_TOKEN --no-cache .` passes the token `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` as argument. This is retrieved in the `Dockerfile` and stored in an environment variable. This environment variable is used in the `nuget.config` file as `$TOKEN_ENV`.

When the restoring of the nuget package of project 1 is carried out with the command `RUN dotnet restore "Project2.API/Project2.API.csproj"`, the following error is displayed:

```
error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://<localdomain>/api/v4/projects/<project1_id>/packages/nuget/index.json. [/src/Project2.API/Project2.API.csproj]
```

I also tried to replace a keyword by the token in the `nuget.config` file with the command `RUN sed -i "s/PASSWORD/$TOKEN_ENV/" nuget.config` (see the line commented in the Dockerfile`above) after copying the`nuget.config` file and after filling the environment variable with the token.

```
<add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PASSWORD" />
```

A reading of the file shows the keyword is replaced by `[MASKED]` and not by the token. So, I still get the same error.

Note that the project 2 has a token access to project 1 with a Gitlab's configuration in the project 1 (Project 1 > Settings > CI/CD > Access token).

How to fix the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a stage *build* in the `gitlab-ci` file by reproducing the same preliminary steps as in the stage *deploy*:

- setting up the certificates;
- replacing the string with the job token.

It works!

I was then able to create an artifact of the result and reuse it for the stage *deploy* by copying it in a docker image.

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - publish/
```

I was thus able to avoid the dependency restoring (causing the problem), the build and the publication in the `Dockerfile` which is simplified by the steps of port exposing, copying of application (artifact) and adding the entrypoint.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OrderService.API.dll"]
```

To conclude,  the use of artifacts allowed me to solve the problem and to structure better the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your %appdata%\NuGet and polish the NuGet.config - it could be you have some redundant settings.